# How to refresh the HTML, including the linked CSS for a QGIS HTML frame?

Tags: qgis-3, html, css, qgis-print-layouts

I am using a referenced css file in an HTML Frame in a QGIS 3.4.2 layout.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="map.css">`

It works great until I have to go and edit the css.  When I make the change, and press `Refresh HTML`, the HTML frame does not use the updated css.  If I exit QGIS, and open again...the changes are present.

Is there a way to configure the QGIS project to watch this file? Or manually reload?

Comment: Maybe you can use embedded CSS (by placing `<style>` in your `<head>`) during the development phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store the HTML file in a directory and open a command prompt in that directory. Then type:

```
python -m http.server 8000    # start local server
```

2. In QGIS enter `http://localhost:8000` as the HTML source:

[image: Screenshot of QGIS 3.2 HTML source - URL with https://localhost:8000 entered]

Now when you change your CSS and press "Refresh HTML" in QGIS, the style is immediately applied to your HTML frame.

PS.: Tested in QGIS 3.2

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one option using a cache busting technique, but that involves editing each HTML Frame when a change is made.  It is not much better, since I'd have to touch every HTML Frame Source and I might as well using the `<style>`tags.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="map.css?version=1.1">`

**UPDATE**
By using a QGIS Expression, I was able to cache bust the CSS whenever the Refresh HTML button was pressed.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="map.css?version=[%to_string(now())%]" >`
[image]

Also submitted a [QGIS Feature Request: 20811](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20811)